# template size_t deduction from constructor's arguments

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out how to make the compiler deduce template parameters based on arguments passed to the constructor. Here's what I tried:

```
#include <array>

template<size_t N, size_t M>
class A {
public:
    A(const std::array<float, N>& n, const std::array<double, M>& m)
        : nElements(n), mElements(m) {
    }

private:
    std::array<float, N>  nElements;
    std::array<double, M> mElements;
};

int main() {
    A<2, 3> a({1.4f, 2.5f}, {3.0, 2.1, 4.8});
    // ^
    // |
    // how can i avoid <2,3> expclicit declaration here?
}
```

Thank you very much for any possible help!

Comment: Which version of C++ are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Thomas's answer says, you can't deduce the class template arguments from the constructor arguments till c++17.

But providing a deduction guide won't work in this case, as pointed out in the comments, since the template arguments of std::array can't be deduced from a brace-init-list.

We can sidestep this issue by creating a deduction guide where the arguments are raw arrays. This solves the problem since the size of raw arrays can be deduced from brace-init-lists.

```
// deduce the size using raw arrays
template<size_t N, size_t M>
A(float const (&)[N], double const (&)[M]) -> A<N,M>;

int main() {
   A a({1.4f, 2.5f}, {3.0, 2.1, 4.8}); // yay
}
```

Answer (score 3):

C++ doesn't deduct the arguments of the class template from arguments passed to the class's constructor, [until C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction).

In versions before C++17, the customary workaround is to create a factory function:

```
template<size_t N, size_t M>
A<N, M> make_A(const std::array<float, N>& n, const std::array<double, M>& m) {
    return A<N, M>(n, m);
}
```

You see examples of these in the standard library as well, such as `std::make_pair` and `std::make_shared`.

Comment: That [also won't work in this case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bf6c3cd06247e6c).  The issue is that `N` and `M` can't be deduced from brace-init-list.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Excellent point... the things people upvote these days eh? ;) I'll leave this up until someone else comes up with a proper answer because it's at least halfway helpful maybe?